# SQL trigger not executing...doing something wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, navicat

I have this:

This is on chars_insert, before.

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM chars WHERE accid = NEW.accid)
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO `char_vars` SET `charid = NEW.charid, `varname` = `NotFirstChar`, `value` = 1;
    END

    INSERT INTO `char_equip`     SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_exp`       SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_jobs`      SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_pet`  SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_points`    SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_profile`   SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_storage`   SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_inventory` SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
END
```

I had just added the IF EXISTS part...which broke the trigger. I am trying to find if one accountid has a character already and if they do, add a variable to the created character saying that this is not their first one. It says the error is on the IF EXISTS line, but I see no error...help please?

Comment: The syntax for triggers and procedures tend to be implementation-specific. Please tag with the dialect of SQL you are using.

Comment: @Turophile 
SQL server 2012, MySQL, and using in Navicat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code in the following way for MySQL:

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM chars WHERE accid = NEW.accid) THEN
            INSERT INTO `char_vars` SET `charid` = NEW.charid, `varname` = `NotFirstChar`, `value` = 1;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `char_equip`     SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_exp`       SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_jobs`      SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_pet`  SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_points`    SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_profile`   SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_storage`   SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
    INSERT INTO `char_inventory` SET `charid` = NEW.charid;
END
```

Also if your `NotFirstChars` meant to be a constant string (not a field name) you should change the quotes: `'NotFirstChars'`